# File being used by another process. Reason, and solution?

Tags: c#

> The process cannot access the file
>   'abc.log' because it is being used by
>   another process.

Hi, I've seen this exception from my application occationaly but I am still trying to fix that, hope I will get some insight from stackoverflow.

In my application I've have defined a WriteToLog function which will write to a log file.
Also the mainForm of  my application will launch a backgroundWorker do some job which also calls the WriteToLog. Maybe two threads access a file will cause a problem? But in my code
I 've already do my best to write flush and close the text file (I think), and here is my code from WriteToLog:

```
 StreamWriter sw = null;
 string newText = "";
 try
 {
     //populate the content for newText
     sw = File.AppendText(LOG_FILE);
     sw.Write(newText);
     sw.Flush();
     sw.Close();
 }
 catch (IOException ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Failed to write to log!\n\t" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
 finally
 {
     if (sw != null)
     {
         sw.Close();
     }
 }
```

I think as long as I flush and close the streamWriter, I should be able call the WriteToLog multi-times and in multi-threads isn't it? Or if I am wrong, could I simple make the file open shared, or there are other reason/solutions?

Answer (score 1):

No; different threads attempting to open the file at the same time will interfere with each other. You could `lock` a shared `object` to force the threads to run one at a time.

Or just use the built-in [.NET tracing functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx); you can configure your `app.config` to write to a file.

Comment: Hi if my understanding is right, the tracing functionality is a debug facility for .NET and I can use it to write log file?

Comment: I need to retest the application, apparently simply lock the LOG_FILE or calling extWriter.Synchronized(File.AppendText(filePath));
instead of sw = File.AppendText(LOG_FILE) didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @pstar: Tracing works for debugging and tracing. By default, for Release builds, tracing is enabled and debugging is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unrelated to your problem, but you can simplify this code a bit by using a `using` statement with your `StreamWriter` instead of having the `finally`.  This also has the added benefit of not having to explicitly call `Close` or `Flush` (closing the stream flushes it, too).

I haven't tried compiling this, but it should be something like:

```
string newText = "";
try
{
    //populate the content for newText
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(LOG_FILE))
    {
        sw.Write(newText);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to write to log!\n\t" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I come across using before but didn't bother to change my code. But think again, even it shouldn't change the way my application working, I change my code to use using block just for clearer code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this from multiple threads, you have to ensure that the file operations are atomic.  It's very likely that Thread A gets past the AppendText and stops e.g. on Write, at which point Thread B gets scheduled and starts writing the same (now locked) file.

One way to handle this is to place a [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) region around the statements presented in your code sample.